# How to redirect .aspx pages to new pages on django site in SEO-friendly way

Tags: python, django, url, seo

I'm in the process of redesigning a site which is being converted from ASPX to django.  We'd like to redirect old urls like this:

/detail.aspx?ID=123

...to...

/articles/123

The problem is in the url pattern matching.  I'd like to match the pattern of the old url like so:

(r'^detail.aspx?ID=(?P\d+)$', 'mygreatview'),

...and from there do a 301 redirect in the view:

```
def mygreatview(request, url_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, url_id=url_id)
    url = '/articles/' + article.url_id
    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(url)
```

The problem is that Django is appending a slash, so the old url gets converted to:

/detail.aspx/?ID=123

...before it gets interpreted by the urls.py.

I tried setting APPEND_SLASH = False, but that seems to cause other problems (squeezing the baloon here) with the other urls.

What am I missing?  Should I be using Apache and mod_rewrite to handle this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That is not your problem. Your problem is that query parameters (`?ID=123`) are not part of the URL. You should just match against `/detail.aspx/` and get the parameters in the view with `request.GET['ID']`.

Actually, you shouldn't do that at all. This level of redirection is much better handled by your web server configuration, eg with mod_rewrite in Apache. There's no need to invoke the overhead of a Django view to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks.  What makes this more complicated is I need to fetch a slug for the new url, so I have to look up the slug by querying w/t/old ID#.  Right now I'm doing this in the view, a 301 > 301.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work, but I'm still not completely happy with it b/c it's a "2-step hop" for the SEO bots.  Here's what I've got:

In Apache conf:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/detail\.aspx(.*) /article$1
```

This sends the querystring as a parameter to a view:

```
def mygreatview(request):
    ID = request.GET['ID']
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, url_id=ID)
    url = '/articles/' + article.URL
    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(url)
```

Wish I could do it in 1 hop, but I've got to use the ID to lookup the slug.  Don't see how I can get around that one, but should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not the following? (haven't tested)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ID=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^/detail.aspx /articles/%1?
```

see http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString for more examples.

This will take your old URLs and redirect them to your django view like it expects without having to put any hacky code in your django view.